# Click event on KML region within Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map created through their [Fusion Tables](https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories) that has a very large number of KML polygons displayed. When you click on one, the usual Google "infowindow" is loaded. However, this is taking a long time so I want to add a loading screen. To do this, **I need to detect a click on a KML region within the map using javascript.** Is this possible?

This is not my map, but is very similar to it: [Example](http://www.montrealgazette.com/news/censusmap.html)

Here's what I've tried:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: { enabled: false },
        query: {
            // query is being placed properly here
        }
    });

    // this doesn't work below
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'kmlClickEvent', function() {
        console.log('KML Clicked');
    });
```

Comment: Hey downvote guys- let me know if I can clarify anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event name is not `kmlClickEvent` (that is the object returned), the event is `click`.

This works for me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function() {
    console.log('KML Clicked');
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/295d56ry/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 41.850033,
      lng: -87.6500523
    },
    zoom: 11
  });

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1mZ53Z70NsChnBMm-qEYmSDOvLXgrreLTkQUvvg'
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function() {
    console.log('KML Clicked');
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```